# Sending connect users to client causes Range Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send an array of users that are connected to the server and send them to the client where I will loop through them.

app.js

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) { 
    socket.on('users', function (data) {
        var clients = io.sockets.sockets;
        socket.emit('clients', { user : clients });
    });
});
```

index.html

```
socket.emit('users', { });

socket.on('clients', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //for(var obj in data) {
    //  console.log(data[obj]);
    //}
});
```

The problem I am having is that it's throwing a RangeError on when trying to pass the users to the client.

There are two questions -

1. Am I doing this correctly? I am new to node.js and networking / server coding as a whole
2. Why would I get a RangeError.

Comment: What is the exact error, with stacktrace?

Comment: socket.emit('clients', { user : clients }); it's having a problem sending that array to the client

Comment: Sorry, I mean you say `"it's throwing a RangeError"`. Please include the whole error in the question. Otherwise it's hard to judge.

Comment: That is the whole error, it's the only line it displays

Comment: It doesn't given any filenames or line numbers where the error is coming from?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/e9bc633ee8475ee4b3d2d0b9f6ac267e

Comment: Thanks, "Max call stack size exceeded" is a critical detail for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since, in the comments, you showed that it's a [stack overflow error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow), it looks like the object pointed to by `io.sockets.sockets` has a circular reference somewhere.

I'm making an assumption here based on what you said in your question, but since you are trying to simply send the list of connected users, maybe you can synthesize the `clients` list prior to sending it out to the clients:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) { 
    socket.on('users', function (data) {
        var clients = io.sockets.sockets.map(function (client) {
          // Derive some value---anything---from the `client` value. Once
          // done that, return the resulting client value. Below, you can
          // see that I have derived nothing, but I recommend that you *do*
          // derive *something*.
          return client;
        });
        socket.emit('clients', { user : clients });
    });
});
```